# How to use same checkbox with same functionality in different Activities

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I have 'rememberLogin' checkbox field in my LoginActivity.I have one more Settings activity,in which i have the rememberLogin checkbox.I want that when i check the LoginActivity's checkbox then the Settings' checkbox should also be checked and vice versa.
Please suggest any useful solutions.
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

In your settings,if not already, you should use a [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) or a [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) according to your target SDK level.

Then when you first display the login page, read the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) for the value of the "Remember login" preference. Then, using an [OnCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html), update the preferences with the value of the checkbox.